# A verb to use with relationship in this context?

Tags: single-word-requests

> It is not clear what relationship this recovery program —————- (with)
> scientific discoveries.

What I want to say is that the relationship between the two is not clear. That is, it’s not clear whether the program takes advantage of scientific discoveries or not, whether scientific findings affect such program or not, and so on.

What is a good verb for relationship in that context? Should I just go with ‘have’? What about ‘hold’? Also, ‘bear’ comes to my mind. I am not sure about any of these. ‘Have’ is too general, used everywhere, so might be not appropriate for a scholarly journal.

Comment: I recommend researching *bear* and *establish* as relevant verbs. I do not put this as an answer, because you have already suggested *bear* yourself and should have told us why you do not want to use it.

Comment: Unless you specify why "have" and "bear" are not satisfactory, this question is off-topic because of requesting an ideal word.

Comment: @fev I am not sure about them. Are they good enough? ‘Have’ is too general, used everywhere, so might be not appropriate for a scholarly journal.

Comment: @fev I added more to the question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is nothing wrong with "have". You say: "‘Have’ is too general, used everywhere, so might be not appropriate for a scholarly journal." However, common, easily understandable language works very well for scholarly journals; abstruse, rare words often impede comprehension and result in poor writing.

If you insist on avoiding "have" but still want something concise, then consider changing the noun "relationship" into a verb:

> It is not clear how this recovery program relates to scientific discoveries.

Answer (score 0):

The verb "entail"  seems usable in   that construction,  provided a small modification is made to the preposition:   "with"  becomes the complex preposition "with respect to".

> (SOED) **entail** **4** Necessitate as a consequence; have as an inevitable accompaniment, involve

- It is not clear what relationship this recovery program *entails with  respect to* scientific discoveries.